# How can I decrypt encrypted value from java like this in nodejs?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt the encrypted value from java code on nodejs

Below is the encrypt method from java

```
public class EncryptUtil {
    public static String getKey()
    {
        return "somekeysomekey+)"; //key length 16!Use this on nodejs
    }

    public static String encryptAES(String ID) throws Exception {

        Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getKey().getBytes(), "AES"); 


        String transform = "AES/ECB/ISO10126Padding";
        String output = "";

        try {
            javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(transform);
            cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            String originStr = ID;

            byte[] input = originStr.getBytes("UTF8");
            byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(input);
            sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
            output = encoder.encode(output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return output;
    }
}

//This is how to encrypt from above
//String encryptText = (String) EncryptUtil.encryptAES("something");
//System.out.println(encryptText) ---> "47gPeqm+0lvKb0VNXF29yQ==";
```

This is my code to decrypt the result of above on nodejs

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = 'somekeysomekey+)';
const algorithm = 'aes-128-ecb';

function decryptFunc(encryptedStr) {
    const base64Decoded = new Buffer(encryptedStr, 'base64').toString('binary');
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key);
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);

    let result = decipher.update(base64Decoded, 'binary', 'binary');
    result += decipher.final('binary');

    return new Buffer(result).toString('utf8');
};
```

But my code is not working..
How can I decrypt on nodejs?..

Comment: What you mean "not working"? Throw exception, return wrong result or something else?

Comment: Is your encryption mode the same?

Comment: Did you try `new Buffer(result, 'binary')` instead? `'utf8'` is the default string encoding. Also, you should avoid using the `'binary'` string encoding and just use Buffers directly. Lastly, use `Buffer.from()` instead of `new Buffer()`.

Comment: One more thing: ECB mode is terrible, avoid it at all costs.

Comment: @talex I know my function is exactly wrong.. It is just one of my a lot of trying to decode. The main point of my question is how to decrypt the encrypted result by the above java code on node js (using crypto module)

Comment: @RohitSaxena Yeah right encryption mode the same

Comment: @mscdex Thanks! I will try what you said. And.. ECB is not my choice. I have to need some information so I call an API to other service.. but it returns the encrypted string by the java code. I have no choice..

Comment: ISO 10126 was withdrawn in 1991, unless you are interoperating with legacy it that should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue thanks to "[CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)" module!

```
//decryption
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const key = "somekeysomekey+)";

const decryptParam = function(param) {
    const value = param ? param.replace(' ', '+') : param;
    if (_.isEmpty(value)) {
        return;
    }

    const hexKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(new Buffer(key).toString('hex'));
    const decryptOpt = {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126};
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, hexKey, decryptOpt);

    return bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```